# Mysql- SELECT Column 'A' even with NULLS

Tags: mysqli

Table A contains student names, table B and C contain classes and the presence of students.
I would like to display all students and attend their presence. The problem is that I can not display all students who did not have a checked presence. 
Where I checked the presence of students it is ok, but if there is no checked presence in a given class, on a given day and in a given subject- nothing is displayed.

My query:

```
SELECT student.id_student, CONCAT(student.name,' ' ,student.surname) as 'name_surname',pres_student_present, pres_student_absent, pres_student_justified, pres_student_late, pres_student_rel, pres_student_course, pres_student_delegation, pres_student_note FROM student
    LEFT JOIN class ON student.no_classes = class.no_classes
    LEFT JOIN pres_student ON student.id_student = pres_student.id_student
    WHERE (class.no_classes = '$class' OR NULL AND pres_student_data = '$data' AND pres_student_id_subject = $id_subject OR NULL)
    GROUP BY student.surname
    ORDER BY student.surname ASC
```

I want to display name_surname always and any other column should have NULL or 1
like:

`Name         | present | absent | just | late | rel | delegation | note |
Donald Trump |    1    |        |      |      |     |            |      |
Bush         |         |        |      |      |     |            |      |
Someone      |    1    |        |      |      |     |            |      |`

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move restrictions on `class`  and `pres_student`tables from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` (LEFT join).

In your case when you perform a restriction in the `WHERE` clause on a table with an `outer join`, the sql engine consider you are performing an `INNER join`

```
SELECT    student.id_student
        , CONCAT(student.name, ' ', student.surname) AS 'name_surname'
        , pres_student_present
        , pres_student_absent
        , pres_student_justified
        , pres_student_late
        , pres_student_rel
        , pres_student_course
        , pres_student_delegation
        , pres_student_note
FROM      student
LEFT JOIN class
       ON student.no_classes = class.no_classes
      AND class.no_classes   = '$class'
LEFT JOIN pres_student
       ON student.id_student      = pres_student.id_student
      AND pres_student_data       = '$data'
      AND pres_student_id_subject = $id_subject
GROUP     BY student.surname
ORDER     BY student.surname ASC
```

Comment: Ok, now i understand that. Great. I needed add `WHERE class.no_class = '$class'` and it works! Without it SQL shows me all students(not in specific class). Thanks a lot.